# div is not Appending with another div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am appending div tag (this div tag is in html part) with another div tag (this div tag is in script) when hover on hyperlink using jquery.

Now, the problem is that after loading page when I hover first time on link, it appends div for sure but then It does not append div tag. So I am just confused with it.

Please help me solve the problem.

Here, I am giving some code.

```
<script id="CollegeInfo" type="text/html">
<div id="${CollegeId}">
    <table width="400px">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <div  class="clgname">
            {{html CollegeName}}
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='color:Gray;'>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td width="10px">
        </td>
        <td valign="top" style='font-size:12px;'>
            <b>Rating :</b></br>
            <div class="grating"></div> // Div tag with whom I am binding html part div tag...
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</script>
```

**Jquery part :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".name").mouseover(function (e) {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "College.asmx/GetInfo",
            data: "{'Id':" + id + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                var info = response.d;
                $("#tbodyCollegeInfo").html($("#CollegeInfo").tmpl(info));

                var block_element = $("#rating");
                $('.grating').append(block_element);

                $('#hdndivCollegeInfo').attr("style","display:block;");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML Part :**

```
<div id="hdndivCollegeInfo" style="display: none;">
        <div class="hoverpreview">
            <div id="rating" class="rating">
                <asp:Rating ID="rtng" runat="server" BehaviorID="rating" ReadOnly="true" StarCssClass="StarCss"
                    FilledStarCssClass="FilledStarCss" EmptyStarCssClass="EmptyStarCss" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStarCss">
                </asp:Rating>
            </div>
            <table>
                <tbody id="tbodyCollegeInfo">
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try changing `var block_element = $("#rating");` to `var block_element = $("#rating").clone();`

Comment: does html tags works inside script?

Comment: @anu .clone is working. but it is showing rating 2 times, one which is originally there and other one is of clone...

Comment: Then add `display:none` to original rating and then change `$('.grating').append(block_element);` to `block_element.appendTo('.grating').show();`. Has it solved your original problem of div not appending on second try?

Comment: @anu yup, solved. thank u so much.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        var block_element = $("#rating").outerHtml();
        $('.grating').append(block_element);
```

EDIT:
are you getting any error on a page?, does it reach the success part of the ajax call?

Comment: nt getting any error. and yes, it reaches at success part of ajax call. After page load, it is showing div for sure bt then on next hover, it does not.

Comment: sorry removed comment, it wasn't related

Comment: Instead of append, i normally use appentTo, wanna try that?  $("#rating").appendTo($('.grating'));   When you see the html code, can you see if the HTML that you've generated is actually appending?  Also you have HTML code inside the script tag?

Comment: it is giving error : TypeError: $(...).outerHtml is not a function

Comment: sorry my bad, suppose to be .html(), instead of .outerHtml()

Answer (score 0):

```
Don't use html tags inside the script directly. use like this
<script id="CollegeInfo" type="text/html">
var appendHtml=
'<div><table width="400px">
<tr>
        <td colspan='3'>
            <div  class='clgname'>            
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='color:Gray;'>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td width='10px'>
        </td>
        <td valign='top' style='font-size:12px;'>
            <b>Rating :</b></br>
            <div class='grating'></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table></div>';

</script> 

In the ajax edit as $('.grating').append(appendHtml);
```